# Yelp API KeyError - how to skip businesses that do not have certain keys

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, yelp

Python 2.7

I am trying to get the 'name','url','display_address' and 'phone' key of the restaurants in certain areas from the Yelp API.

My code did print the info I was looking for until it hit the restaurants that do not have the 'phone' key I guess, because it returned this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/git-folder/api2.py",
> line 175, in <module>
>     print yelp_query(zipcode[i])   File "/Users/git-folder/api2.py", line 166, in yelp_query
>     phone = business[i]["phone"] KeyError: 'phone'
```

My code:

```
def yelp_query(zip_code):
    client = YelpClient(yelp_keys = keys)
    result_json = client.search_by_location(
    location = str(zip_code), term = 'BBQ',
    sort = YelpClient.SortType.BEST_MATCHED, radius=2)
    business = result_json["businesses"]


    for i in range(0,len(business)):
        n = business[i]["name"]
        add = str(business[i]["location"]["display_address"]).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("u'","").replace("'","")
        url = business[i]["url"]
        phone = business[i]["phone"]
        print n, ";",url,";",add,";",phone
```

How do I write an 'IF' statement to just print 'none' if there's no phone keys for certain business instead of stopping there and giving me this error?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a dictionary and are not sure that it contains a certain key, you can use the [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method and specify a default. In your case since you want `None` to be returned when the key does not exist you can use the `get()` call without a second parameter. `get()` without the second parameter returns `None` by default. This is what you need:

```
n = business[i].get('phone', None)
```

If the 'phone' key is not present, `n` is assigned `None` which you can later check with `if n:`

Comment: Just a small point `None` is the default value returned if the key is not found by `.get()`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid True. Updated the answer to that effect. Thanks